# Not sure why I'm getting "An object reference is required for the non-static field"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, xna, visual-c#-express-2010

My code is below. Any help would be appreciated. I apologize in advance if it's a simple mistake - I'm still a beginner at C# (and object oriented in general).

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    public void Update()
    {
        Levels level = new Levels();
        Game1 mainGame = Game1;
        Levels.AliensSetUp(1, 2, 50, 0, 0, 0, mainGame);
    }
}

class Levels
{
    public void AliensSetUp(int numberRows, int numberColumns, int spaceBetween, int XStart, int YStart, int AlienType, Game1 mainGame)
}
```

The error is on the "mainGame" in "Levels.AliensSetUp(1, 2, 50, 0, 0, 0, mainGame)". I've also tried replacing "mainGame" with just "game1" but I get an error for that too. Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: You need to learn about [static members vs instance members in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629(v=vs.71).aspx). There are some fundamental object-oriented programming concepts that you're missing.

Comment: You're trying to call the `AliensSetUp` method using the name of the class (`Levels`).  Instead, you need to use the instance of the object you created (`level`).  Based on the code in your question, it would be `level.AlensSetUp(...)`.

Comment: That fixed it - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Levels is not static.  You have "new" up the Levels class and then call its AliensSetUp() method.  Ex:

```
var levels = new Levels(); 
levels.AliensSetup(...)
```

Comment: He didn't do anything with Game1. He's trying to assign the type itself to an instance of the type. He has no clue what "instance" and "static" mean.

Comment: Thanks, clarified that.  It should be: var levels = new Levels();
levels.AliensSetup...

Comment: I think that belongs in the answer, not in a comment.

Comment: Hey, I actually do have "Levels level = new Levels();" in my code. I had to simplify my code for stack overflow and I forgot to add that. Thank you for your help though.